# C# - boolean property value wont change :(

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm setting initial `boolean` value (just because of testing) in my `Map` method, so I set there `HasChildrens` value to `true` so I could check later in my app when I manually change that value is it really gonna change because I was suspicious it's not changing.. And unfortunatelly I was right :/

Flow goes like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CompDTO>> GetCompanies()
{
     var companies = await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();

     var result = GetMappedData(companies);

     foreach (CompDTO comp in result)
     {
        comp.HasChildrens = false;
     }

   return result;
}


private IEnumerable<CompDTO> GetDataMapped(IEnumerable<Company> companiesList)
{
    return companiesList.Select(company => Map(company));
}


private CompDTO Map(Company company)
{
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        Title = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildrens = true
    };
}
```

And everytime when I check result from my `GetCompanies()` method and the value of `HasChildrens`, I am really supprised it's allways true! Even if I wrote in my method `comp.HasChildrens = false;`

This is really giving me headache :D

Thanks for any kind of help!

Cheers

Comment: Please add your CompDTO to your post.

Comment: Consider returning IQueryable<CompDTO> instead of IEnumerable<CompDTO> in GetDataMapped. This won't solve your problem but materializing your query before sending it will( as the answer suggests). But it will make it clearer that GetDataMapped method will return a query and not materialized objects.
And another thing, consider using Automapper in your project, it will simplify your code a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> ```
> var result = GetMappedData(companies);
> ```

saves the [*query*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution) to the `result` variable, not the results of the query. This is because `GetMappedData` returns a query to begin with, not an object that implements the `IEnumerable` interface (such as `List`).

On the next line, the `foreach` loop enumerates the query, so the query finally starts executing. It successfully changes the `HasChildrens` property of each element, but the sequence itself does not go anywhere.

On the next line, you return `result`, which, again, is the query, not the result of the query. When the caller of `GetCompanies()` tries to enumerate that query, it starts enumeration again, producing a new sequence of different instances of `CompDTO`, and this time there is no `foreach` loop to amend them before proceeding, so you observe the property value as `false`.

Materialize your query when you first call it:

```cs
var result = GetMappedData(companies).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please in short terms explain to me what means saves the query to the result variable? (Is there data which is returned by `GetMappedData` method or not?  and what does it mean to me as a developer when my methods returns a query, and not the results of the query? and what does it mean `Materialize` my query? What is that?

Comment: @MateuszRek Please click the link.